# See total number of entries in Global TODO list

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Would it be possible to list the total number of entries in a global todo agenda view? I would like to have a quick way to estimate progress daily.

So instead of:

```
Global list of TODO items of type: NEXT
  life:       NEXT Configure global todo lists   :emacs:
```

I would like to see something like:

```
Global list of TODO items of type: NEXT (1 remaining)
  life:       NEXT Configure global todo lists   :emacs:
```

Is this possible? I know I could use statistics cookies in my life file, but I would prefer to have an overview of TODOs in my agenda view (I use 3 such lists after my Daily Agenda view).

Comment: I use the line number to calc the total number of TODO list now, just the last line number minus 3 (or 2 if you have less TODO keywords)...

Comment: @zhouji I used to do this also, but I have three such lists in one agenda view and this became too tedious or I'm just too lazy and I stopped.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `org-agenda-finalize-hook`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook
          (lambda ()
            (save-excursion
              (goto-char (point-min))
              (when (re-search-forward
                     "Global list of TODO items of type: [[:upper:]]*" nil t)
                (insert (propertize
                         (format " (%s remaining)"
                                 (- (count-lines (point-min) (point-max)) 2))
                         'face 'font-lock-comment-face))))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll get back to you after I have time to test it.